# Hidden Markov Model or Neural Network?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, hidden-markov-models

I am working on project where I am supposed to develop a system that detects fraud in credit card transactions. I am new to the concepts of Hidden Markov Model and Neural Networks. I am now confused as to which one should I go for. Is it possible to integrate the two? Please advise me, thanks.

Comment: This should probably go over to http://cs.stackexchange.com/ since it involves selecting an algorithm or approach to solving a problem, but doesn't involve programming itself.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Thanks, let me go over ask it that side.